# How to plot overlaying shapes onto an Orthographic Plot in Plotly?

Tags: 3d, plotly, geo, orthographic

I am trying to identify a way to plot certain figures (semi-spheres or cones, for instance) onto an existing Figure with set orthographic projection created with Plotly.
I have utilized the code kindly provided here by Igor Comune: https://igorcomune.medium.com/data-science-how-to-plot-3d-interactive-globe-map-4dfba1b6e070

I now have a 3D Globe with geographic overlay, and some scattergeo points dotting the Globe. In some of those scattergeo points I would like to center shapes, ideally by utilizing Azimuth-Elevation Coordinates in order to showcase some umbrella coverages for some points of interest.

Any particular section of the documentation or any relevant guide that I can make use of?

I tried looking a bit into the documentation and I feel like doing a fig.add_mesh3d could perhaps be a solution here, but not sure how to pass Az-El coord pairs in order to obtain the desired shape centered on the scattergeo trace (centering which I believe I can do with xsrc, ysrc, zsrc?)

Comment: I don't think that there is enough information here to help. This a programming code forum. Where's the code? Since you're plotting spatial data, you probably want to use spatial polygons to add the content you wanted to add. Read about spatial Plotly for Python [here](https://plotly.com/python/maps/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I did not add the code since besides adding a couple more scattergeo objects to the figure, the code does not deviate from the one provided in the URL above. Bubble plots seem to be close to what I require, except the bubbles would have to be 3D and overlayed on the globe. Will look into it. If adding the code is required for a better overview, I can.